# How do I set the timeout for a WebSocket connection in a vapor swift app?

Tags: swift, websocket, backend, vapor

I have noticed that in my vapor swift app the websocket connection to a client ends after a specific timeout. How do I change that timout, more specific, how do I disable it?

I have found resources for other technologies, but not for vapor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the connection alive, you can schedule repeated task with a fixed delay:

```
 socket.eventLoop.scheduleRepeatedTask(initialDelay: .seconds(5), delay: .seconds(10)) { task -> Void in
        guard !socket.isClosed else {
            task.cancel()
            return
        }
        socket.send(raw: UUID().uuidString, opcode: .ping)
    }
```